# How to check if a session has timed out and redirect the user back to the login screen in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

I have configured authentication in Rails 3.2.17 without Devise.  I want to redirect the user back to the login screen after the session has ended which is 30 minutes and let them know that the session has ended and they must login again.

I attempted to add an attribute :login_expiry onto the user and set the time 10 minutes after the session end time, in my session controller after I have found the user:

user.login_expiry = 40.minutes.from_now
   user.save

where login_expiry is a datetime attribute.

If the user session has ended and it is within 10 minutes after the session ended then the user should be presented with the login screen and a flash "your session has ended. Please log in again."

However what I have found is that the login_expiry is not being updated on the user object.  The database is rolling back.

I would really like anyones help on this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need something that Devise doesn't handle out of the box? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Timeoutable

Comment: Hi I decided not devise because I understand how authentication works, pulling my code out and putting devise would be more hassle than it is worth.

Comment: Sorry I misread this the first time round I read it as "with Devise" my bad!

Answer (score 0):

at user's successful login you can do following:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 30.minutes
```

Then, every time authenticated user do something do something, do something like following:

```
if session[:expires_at] < Time.current
  # sign out and redirect to login page
end
```

Usually we check whether user is logged in or not at every page, in that case we can put them in `ApplicationController` and use `before_action` hook of rails controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :check_login_session

  private

  def check_login_session
    if session[:expires_at] < Time.current
      # sign out and redirect to login page
    end
  end
end
```

As `ApplicationController` is usually the parent of every controller, so before every controller call it will `check_login_session`.

Comment: Hi sadaf2605, thanks for your answer just wondering where I would put the code that performs the check on the session time out?